# H2 memory DB test can't find table TAB

Tags: java, h2

I use H2 memory DB to do my test integration and my real BD is oracle DB

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;Mode=Oracle
```

When I want to use this SQL to check if my table exists

```
SELECT TNAME FROM TAB WHERE TNAME='myTableName'
```

But in the execution test, I got the error message "Table "TAB" not found".

What could I do to use this oracle table?

Comment: can you show us your entities please? How you generate your table, via entities by scripts ...

Comment: I don't use entities to create this table, it creates dynamically with SQL, when I run the script in the real DB I could get the table name but when I use  the memory DB with `jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`, It can't find the table TAB anymore

Comment: did you checked your h2 table? does the table exist?

Comment: usually table names are in upper case

Comment: @ClausRadloff true

Comment: To rule out the obvious: you **did** create table named `TAB`? Please show us the `create table tab ....` statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The table TAB is an ancient data dictionary table of Oracle

Comment: So why do you expect H2 to have an Oracle specific table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, my real DB is oracle, and I use h2 memory to do my integration test `jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;Mode=Oracle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the table TAB in integration script sql and simule the fonctionnement Oracle ...